# Combined two path to make a function in Javascript

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm sorry if this as already been asked, but I have this code :

```
$('html').click(function () {
    nbClic = 0;
});
```

and this code :

```
$('#tableAutresPlacements > tbody > tr').click(function () {
nbClic = 0;
});
```

and I want to merge the condition to make them do th same thing. A bit like :

```
$('html').click(function () || $('#tableAutresPlacements > tbody > tr').click(function () {
    nbClic = 0;
});
```

Do know if it's possible to do such things? If it is, can you tell me :) ?

Comment: Since everything is a descendant of `html`, there is no need to have the second event handler. The event will just bubble up.

Comment: If I don't precise this path : $('#tableAutresPlacements > tbody > tr'), the click on it does not work since it's dynamicly generated!

Comment: Whether the element exists or not is irrelevant. Proof: https://jsfiddle.net/yr1tfahk/

Comment: It's actually exactly the other way round: `$('#tableAutresPlacements > tbody > tr')` won't work if that element doesn't exist at that moment. But maybe what you actually want is `$(document.body).on('click', ''#tableAutresPlacements > tbody > tr', ...);` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify multiple selectors:

```
$('html, #tableAutresPlacements > tbody > tr')
       ^--use a comma to separate the multiple selectors
```

but as others have commented, all elements in the page are a descendant of `html` anyways, so the second `tbody > tr` part is redundant.